# copy image before applying filter with php image filter

Tags: php, imagefilter

i'm applying filter to images with php `imagefilter`, filter are successfully added to images, but the issue is that the old image does not exist after applying filter, pls how can i achieve having both the old image and new image.
Thanks.

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('dave.png');
if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE))
{

imagejpeg($im, 'dave.png');
 }
 else

  {
  echo 'Conversion  failed.';
  }

imagedestroy($im);
 ?>
```

Comment: go for [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopy.php)

Comment: @w01f can you give example on how to use it ,thanks

Comment: there is that manual and it has lots of examples … next time also search before asking ;)